# Get .xib height to use it in the heightForRowAtIndexPath function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, height, uitableview

I have created a custom .xib that contains a TableViewCell that contains a `UIImageView` And `UILabel`.

I want to know TableViewCell height in the .xib file, not to set it manually in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Also is there a property of `UIImage` to have the height of the TableViewCell when i change it by hand in the .xib file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewCell is actually a UIView, so when you load it from xib the frame property can help you:

cell.frame.size.height

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't get the cell from within the area where you want to return that height, inside heightForCellAtIndexPath.