# Getting Height From a XIB

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xib, nib

I'm creating a custom UITableViewCell from an xib. However, the cells don't automatically fit the same height I set in the xib file. Is there a way to get the height of the xib in the heightForRowAtIndexPath so that I can accurately set the height without having to hard code it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get .xib height to use it in the heightForRowAtIndexPath function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738209/get-xib-height-to-use-it-in-the-heightforrowatindexpath-function)

Comment: Does the custom tableview cell need to change in size at all? Or will is always be the one size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the UITableView on the storyboard, or view etc, within the interface builder you can set the cell height to match your custom cell nib's height.

Go to the Utilities panel and select the tab as highlighted in blue in the picture below. Set the row height here.

[image]

I hope this helps with what you are looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

You can also use this delegate method of table View

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      //Height same as your XIB of cell
}
```

Comment: The question asked specifically how to do it without hard coding the value. He is asking not to do it this way.

Comment: @Vlad: Ok. I din't see that. My mistake